# How to get user badge names by id in discord php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to develop a small script that will show all the badges of x discord user just by entering the user id, but I don't know how to do it.

This is what the php api shows

```
{
"id": "1090372582781497424",
"username": "shaydew",
"avatar": "4bda9edf7144f97f6d4375829662b9c0",
"discriminator": "0001",
"public_flags": 4194561,
"flags": 4194561,
"banner": "a_047a91b3560dff93f74ebfdb6810578b",
"accent_color": null,
"global_name": "shay",
"avatar_decoration": "v2_a_37dc2b53b273a457ff19ac2e3fda7e4c",
"display_name": "shay",
"banner_color": null
}
```

"public_flags" is supposed to get the names of the flags, there is the problem, how can I get it?

Here I show my little code in php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

    
    $discordId = $_GET["discord_id"];
    $token = "";
    $url = "https://discord.com/api/users/{$discordId}";
    
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Bot {$token}\r\n",
            'methods'  => 'GET',
        ),
    );
    
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($response === false) {
        die('Error fetching data from Discord API');
    }
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $response;

    
    
?>
```

What I want it to show me is the following:

```
https://discordlookup.mesavirep.xyz/v1/user/604779545018761237

"badges": [
"HOUSE_BRAVERY",
"EARLY_VERIFIED_BOT_DEVELOPER",
"ACTIVE_DEVELOPER"
],
```

Could someone help me to get the names of the badges of x discord user?, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the received JSON in an array, and recreate a new JSON containing only the required data:

```
$arrResponse = json_decode($response, true);
$badges = json_encode (['badges' => $arrResponse['badges']] /*, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT*/);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $badges;
```

Comment: null appears when entering a user id
https://i.imgur.com/B8ISwl7.png

Comment: @paulita I assumed that $response is a valid JSON string containing a `badges` key.
Try do dump $response and $arrResponse for debugging before re-encoding it :
`echo "$response<br><pre>";`  `print_r($arrResponse);`  `die;`

Comment: @paulita also note that I have tryed with the test URL that you have provided *(https://discordlookup.mesavirep.xyz/v1/user/604779545018761237)*. 
While the first JSON that you have posted does not contains any 'badges' key.

Comment: ah, seeing this I don't know how they do it in js
https://github.com/mesalytic/discord-lookup-api/blob/main/server.js 